# Paste a chunk of text from stdin to a specific location in a file

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I'm trying to figure out how to efficiently copy-paste from X application to the terminal. Specifically I want to highlight a text section in my web browser, then paste this commented to a file after the shebang line.

the code I have so far is this:

```
xclip -o | sed 's/^/#/' | sed '2n' myscript.pl
```

the first command takes the text that I have highlighted in my browser
the second command comments the lines by adding # 
the last bit does not work..

what I am trying to do here is append the text after line number 2 to my script. But obviously I am doing this wrong.. Does anyone have a helpful suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` `read` for safely handling all types of input, including input with special characters and multiple lines. This requires an intermediate file:

```
 xclip -o | sed -e 's/^/#/g' -e '$s/$/\n/' > TMP && sed -i '1r TMP' den && rm TMP
```

Comment: I am getting this error when I try your solution: sed: -e expression #1, char 240: unknown command: `I'

Comment: @Dan-SimonMyrland, changed the answer to handle multiple line input and all sorts of special characters.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` only operates on one input stream (either a pipe or a file), if you are using the output of `xclip` as the data stream then you can't also tell `sed` to read from a file. Instead you could use command substitution to store the modified output, and use that in a separate command. How about:

```
sed "2i$(xclip -o | sed 's/^/#/')" myscript.pl
```

This will print the amended file to stdout, if you want to edit the file itself then use the `-i` flag.